# how to add file extension on gedit (windows version)

Tags: php, cakephp, gedit

I´m trying to add a .ctp file to gedit on windows, because I have a project that use cake php framework. I like to add .ctp files to be interpreted like .php files. How to achieve this on windows ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must edit the file `php.lang`  in `C:\Program Files\gedit\share\gtksourceview-2.0\language-specs\`
change the the line

```
<property name="globs">*.php;*.php3;*.php4;*.phtml;*.phtml</property>
```

to

```
<property name="globs">*.php;*.php3;*.php4;*.phtml;*.phtml;*.ctp</property>
```

and restart gedit